# Where is OpenCL kernels in AMD SDK

Tags: opencl

`clMath` is an open-source project provided by AMD. It contains a clBLAS library ([source code](https://github.com/clMathLibraries/clBLAS)). I checked the repo, and found out that all functions are written in C, not in OpenCL. Did I looking at wrong files? Where are the OpenCL kernels? How can a C function be used in parallel computing?

Actually, there is a folder named `clTemplates` and all `.cl` files are in this folder. I suppose that when a function is called, it will generate a `.cl` file based on one of the files in `clTemplates` folder, right? Hence, there are only 39 basic OpenCL kernels.

More generally, I want to know how does AMD SDK work?

Comment: What do you mean 'how does it work'? What are you trying to do, or what isn't clear to you?

Comment: The CL code does not need to be in .cl files. In fact, does the library come with a bunch of .cl files? The answer is clear "no". The code is stored as strings in the library, and compiled at run-time. In this specific case, the CL code is build to a string using macros, no it is not so easy to follow where the kernel is really created. Because depending on multiple things clBLAS builds the kernels differently.

Comment: I want to know what happened when I call a clBLAS function in my C++ program, will there be OpenCL codes generated? What are they? Where are they? Are they optimised? Can I tweak one or two operations to achieve a better performance?

Comment: I don't know how clBLAS works, but an application can generate OpenCL C in-memory and submit it to the driver. It doesn't have to land in a .cl file at all.